# Controlling conditional alert, and scrolling towards it in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a conditional alert message, that I want to show, depending on a state, that determinates, if the user can submit a message

```
{this.state.showAlert &&
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-warning">
  <button type="button" onClick={()=> this.setState({showAlert: false})} class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="alert-heading">Warning!</h4>
  <p class="mb-0">Please fill in all the requested fields, before submitting a message.  <a class="alert-link">I will look at answer your message as quickly as possible. Thank you</a>.</p>
</div>
}

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style={{width: '100%'}} aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<div ref={el => { this.el = el; }} />
</div>
```

here I render the message and make a Jsx element to scroll towards the bottom

in my handler, I have a conditional check

```
onSubmitHandler = () =>{
    if(this.state.isUsernameCorrect == false || this.state.isEmailCorrect == false){
        this.setState({
        showAlert: true
      })
       this.scrollToBottom('hello')

    }else{
      this.setState({
        showAlert: false
      })
    }
    console.log('submitted')
  }
```

my issue is that the first time the alert is not properly set. I think this happens due to the fact, that setState is asynchronous.

So second time you click the button it scrolls correctly.

I have tried using a callback to setState but with no luck

```
onSubmitHandler = () =>{
    if(this.state.isUsernameCorrect == false || this.state.isEmailCorrect == false){
        this.setState({
        showAlert: true
      },  this.scrollToBottom('hello'))
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I provided the answer in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the issue was, that I wasn't executing the function properly, so it was only called, when the submit handler was called the first time.

Of course, this should be done using a function call instead.

```
onSubmitHandler = () =>{
if(this.state.isUsernameCorrect == false || this.state.isEmailCorrect == false){
    this.setState({
    showAlert: true
  }, () =>  
  this.scrollToBottom('hello'))

}else{
  this.setState({
    showAlert: false
  })
}
console.log('submitted')
```

}

I made use of the callback argument in the setState, so I'm sure the state is set properly, before firing the function.